# XPath selection from path in XML content

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <name>The name</name>
  <long>
    <path>
      <value>Some Value</value>
    </path>
  </long>
  <field>/root/name</field>
  <field>/root/long/path/value</field>
</root>
```

and I want to select these paths in the field tags however, when I try the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/field[1]" />
```

all I get is the text value of the field. Is there a way of selecting the correct node from those values?

Answer (score 1):

You need some form of dynamic evaluation. I believe there is a non-standard function `eval()` (or `evaluate()` in some implementations) that allows you to use dynamic xpath.

Which XPath processor are you using, and XPath 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

**Such kind of dynamic evaluation is not supported even in XSLT 2.0**.

Maybe the XSLT processor you are using supports EXSLT's [**`dyn:evaluate()`**](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html) extension function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the node that contains "/root/node" then your xpath would be:

`//*[.='/root/name']`

this is called a [predicate](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), where the`*` matches any node and the `.` is the current node.